# Public variables and Workbook_Open function

Tags: excel, vba

I want to initialize some variable (like the ranges for graphs) in the Workbook_Open function in ThisWorksheet. This is done like:

```
Public ChartSizePosition As Range
Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set ChartSizePosition = Range("B8:I25")
    Worksheets("Übersicht").Range("A1").Value = "q3f"
End Sub
```

Afterwards I want to access the variable from some Sub in a module. But there is always given an error "Runtime error 424. Object necessary".
The Workbook_Open code is definitely reached.

Anyone can give me a suggestion?

Best regards and thanks!

Comment: You have to refer to `ThisWorkbook.ChartSizePosition` rather than just `ChartSizePosition`, or move the declaration to a normal module.

Comment: Also where is the `Range("B8:I25")`? You don't want the range to be picked from wrong worksheet? Change it to something like `Set ChartSizePosition = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B8:I25")`

Comment: @Rory: That is a valid answer. You may want to put that as an answer so that OP can accept it. Comments are temporary :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a public variable to a class module (which ThisWorkbook is) you have to refer to the variable as a member of that class. So you have to refer to `ThisWorkbook.ChartSizePosition` rather than just `ChartSizePosition`.

Alternatively you can move the declaration to a normal module.